# How can I download multiple email streams using Microsoft Graph SDK's batched requests?

Tags: c#, batch-processing, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to download multiple emails using a single Microsoft Graph SDK call.

This is the code I'm using:

```
   foreach (var emailId in emailIds)
   {
       var request = graphServiceClient.Users[EmailAddress].Messages[emailId].Request();
       request.Headers.Add(new HeaderOption("Accept", "message/rfc822"));

       batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(request);
   }

   var result = await graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent, cancellationToken);
```

This call results in the exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest
> Message: Invalid batch payload format.

What do I need to change to get this to work, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by email stream? Message body including attachments?

Comment: Yes, if you call that request by itself it will return a Stream that can be saved as an .eml file. But I want to save batches of emails. not one at a time.

Comment: I would guess that you can' request streams per batch. You have to parallelize on a higher level like using `Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: Thanks - I'm already doing that. It becomes a bit more complex because of throttling issues hence my preference to use the built-in batching mechanism, but I've got a working solution using a Semaphore to control the number of requests. I think I'll stick with this for now.

Comment: I am trying this not too, you can get further with the following code: ```var request = client.Users[mailbox].Messages[mailId].Content.ToGetRequestInformation();
var requestId = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(request);```
However I currently struggle with getting it back via `var mailStream = await response.GetResponseByIdAsync<Stream>(requestId);`